# How to pass variables in PHP page to another page without using form?

Tags: php, facebook

My project using related to Facebook. When user login `$user` will variable that in this page is know this variable but for other page is no. So  I want to know how to pass variables by using PHP without form? I am trying with declare session already but it is not possible because it's in if condition

```
        <?php 
             if ($user):            
                 echo 'Name:'. $user_profile['id']."<br />";
                 echo 'Name:'. $user_profile['name']."<br />";
             else: 
        ?>
```

`$user_profile['id']` is what I want to pass to the other page.

Comment: Try to use session...!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php

Comment: why it is not possible in if conditionn?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_profile'] = $user_profile['id'];
```

and use session variable every page you want the stored variables

on every other pages you can retrieve the variable value like that

```
    session_start();
    $user_profile['id'] = $_SESSION['user_profile'];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a **session** to store data and use in other pages

just add a session at the top of your pages

```
session_start();
```

then

```
//On first page
$_SESSION['user_profile'] = $user_profile['id'];

//On second page
$user_profile = $_SESSION['user_profile'];
```

so now you can echo it

```
echo $user_profile;
```

`UPDATED`

i think you can do this with `cookies` as well

```
//One first page
$_COOKIE['variable_name'] = $variable_value;

//On second page
$variable_value = $_COOKIE['variable_name'];
```

the difference between those two is that in first case variable will be stored in a session on server side while cookies will store variable in client side.

Answer (score 1):

Try [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) ..

Use this one on the first page

```
    <?php
    $bar = $user_profile['id'];
    apc_store('foo', $bar);
?>
```

and do this on other pages

```
<?php
    apc_fetch('foo');
    ?>
```

Use  alternative php catch .reduce 50% time than sessions

[APC Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.apc.php)

[apc_store](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-store.php) — Cache a variable in the data store

[apc_fetch](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-fetch.php) — Fetch a stored variable from the cache