# How can we pass a variable of one page to another page without using sessions and forms

Tags: php

I can't start the new session because I have already started a session.So help me out to pass a variable form one page to another page without using sessions and forms.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119366/how-to-pass-variables-in-php-page-to-another-page-without-using-form

Comment: try json encode and decode......

Comment: <a href="newpage/?abc=data_var">link</a>
to other page
<?php $_GET['abc'];?>

Comment: @NagarajS in that they used sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it in a URL parameter, which can be as easy as generating a new link.

```
http://www.yousite.com/new_page.html?variable_to_pass=some_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the header function like this

```
header('location:http://www.yousite.com/new_page.html?variable_name=some_value')
```

and access this `variable_name` to the next page use `$_GET['variable_name'];`

Comment: OP doesn't want to use `<form>`